# Python pairSum function with Dictionaries

Tags: python, class, function, sum, dictionary

I'm trying to write a function pairSum(data, value), in which if a list "data" contains two distict numbers whose sum equals "value," the function returns true. I accomplished this using a list but is there a more efficient way I could write this function using dictionaries?

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify whether the list has *pairs* of numbers or just *single* numbers.

Comment: My original function had individual numbers and I'm trying to implement the same basic function using a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a set.

```
def pairSum(data, value):
  s = set()
  for i in data:
    if (value - i) in s:
      return True
    else:
      s.add(i)
  else:
    return False
```

Comment: Nice! Your solution is O(n), we really don't need to calculate all possible combinations here.

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import combinations

pairSum = lambda data, value: any(sum(i) == value for i in combinations(data, 2))
```

**EDIT**
Pedro Werneck pointed out that a membership test on a `set()` might be more efficient:

```
pairSum = lambda data, value: value in set(sum(i) for i in combinations(data, 2))
```

**FURTHER EDIT**
I took Ignacio's advice, and tested the two methods using `timeit`. The results are below:

for all tests, the functions tested are identical to the ones I posted in my original answer (above).

timeit number of executions is 10,000

`data = range(100)`

```
Test Value    Generator      Set
```

```
         1     0.02824     10.84905
```

```
       101     0.66934     10.77293
```

```
       197    11.07062     10.73978
```

So the conclusion appears to be that the generator operates faster on average, with both worst case times for set and generator about the same.

Comment: any() does a linear search, so doing value in set(sum(i) for i in combinations(data, 2)) is probably more efficient.

Comment: @Pedro: Generating a set will still be linear, so you save little if anything.

Comment: @PedroWerneck: Hmmm, I'm not sure. I think it would depend on the size of `combinations`. `any(sum(i)...` is a generator expression and doesn't require all of the values to be computed before evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

Not a dictionary, but you can build all combinations and check if your value is in that set.

```
import itertools

def pairSum(data, value):
    return value in set(map(sum, itertools.combinations(data, 2)))
```

If your list don't contain zeroes or negative values, you can keep only the values lower than the target in the list, since summing an equal or higher value to anything else in the list won't match:

```
import itertools

def pairSum(data, value):
    data = [v for v in data if v < value]
    return value in set(map(sum, itertools.combinations(data, 2)))
```